# Installation of a symfony2 bundle (DoctrineCouchDBBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I wish to install the bundle into my symfony project. However, I am coming across a few issues. Please accept my ignorance if the answer is trivial but I've tried searching for a solution but alas, I've found nothing.

In my **deps** file, I have:

```
[doctrine-couchdb]
  git=http://github.com/doctrine/couchdb-odm.git
[DoctrineCouchDBBundle]
  git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle.git
  target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineCouchDBBundle
```

I run the **bin/vendors install** command

In my **autoload.php** file I have:

```
'Doctrine\\ODM\\CouchDB'=> __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-couchdb/lib',
```

I've registered the bundle:

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\CouchDBBundle\DoctrineCouchDBBundle()
```

When I run php app/console I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\CouchDBBundle\DoctrineCouchDBBundle' not found in /var/www/symfony2.test/app/AppKernel.php on line 22
```

I've noticed that for MongoDB ODM you have:

```
[doctrine-mongodb]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/mongodb.git
```

is there not a doctrine-couchdb repo? Have you used this bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed target to

```
    target= /bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/CouchDBBundle
```

so now looks like this

```
    [DoctrineCouchDBBundle]
      git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle.git
      target=/bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/CouchDBBundle
```

because I noticed that name space for couchdb bundle is

```
    namespace Doctrine\Bundle\CouchDBBundle;
```

therefore adding

```
    new Doctrine\Bundle\CouchDBBundle\DoctrineCouchDBBundle()
```

to AppKernel will fail, if installation location does not match namespace/class_name.

Detailed setup and configuration here [DoctrineCouchDBBundle Git Hub Issue Log](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle/issues/1)

For those that are new to Symfony 2 bundling architecture, you probably wonder what configuration keys are mandatory and available for bundles. Info can be obtained from:

```
    bundle_dir/bundle_name/.../configuration.php
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** :

1.) Check that you also have installed and autoloaded `Doctrine\CouchDB`

2.) in your git installation

`target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineCouchDBBundle` should probably be

`target=/bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineCouchDBBundle`  (notice Symfony => Doctrine)

3.) Then change

`'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',`

to

`'Doctrine'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),`

---

Off the top of my head I'd assume either these things:

1.) Cache

2.) `'Doctrine\\ODM\\CouchDB'=> __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-couchdb/lib',`
should be above any higher level namespaces ('Doctrine', 'Doctrine\Common')

so it should look like this:

```
'Doctrine\\ODM\\CouchDB'=> __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-couchdb/lib',
'Doctrine\\DBAL'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
```

3.) some configuration missing in config.yml

Comment: probably a stupid question, but do you have autoloads for other parts? like Doctrine\Bundle and Doctrine\CouchDB ?

Comment: also shouldn't `target=/bundles/**Symfony**/Bundle/DoctrineCouchDBBundle` be actually `target=/bundles/**Doctrine**/Bundle/DoctrineCouchDBBundle` ?

Comment: Yups, I changed it to: target=/bundles/**Doctrine**/Bundle/DoctrineCouchDBBundle

Comment: But it didn't change anything, do i need to autoload the bundle ni autoload? how would I do that? thanks!

Comment: bah too long to explain in comments, check my update in answer

Comment: Excellent it worked! Such a simple answer. the more you know! thank you kind sir! much appreciated :-)

Comment: You're welcome, I've actually learned something myself while helping you ^^